# Changing visibility of ProgressBar causes force close

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a layout containing a WebView, and a ProgressBar centred on top of it. The progress bar needs to be shown and hid programatticaly (as web content loads). However, setting the ProgressBar to be visible using `loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, causes a force close. If the ProgressBar is visible by default it works fine. I will paste all appropriate code if needed, but I suspect I'm doing something fundamentally and simply wrong.

(should have force-close tag but neither it nor forceclose exists and I can't create it.)

Okay, code. The setVisibility is simply:

```
  public void nowLoading() {
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

nowLoading is called... via javascript, with addJavascriptInterface on the WebView. Ahh... I imagine the WevView is in a different Thread. How do I solve that?

Comment: Please post the Exception you get on LogCat.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://pastebin.com/2KYUdjYB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably changing the visibility from the wrong thread. Are you doing the visibility change in a new Thread you started with `Thread.start()`?

EDIT: use a `Handler` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Send a Message to the Handler and then do the visibility change from the Handler. Or use `View.post` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: Nope. How do I make sure I'm in the right thread? Is there any way I'm in the wrong one if I didn't start one myself? I'm very new to Android.

Comment: Post some code: easiest way to resolve it. The entire method in which you call `setVisibility`, and any other method that calls that one (if its not a lifecycle method such as `onCreate`).

Comment: I think this is what you want:

Comment: `Thread [<8> WebViewCoreThread] (Suspended (exception ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException))  ` says it quite clearly: you are on the wrong thread somewhere. You'll need to look at your code and figure out where you are calling things from the wrong thread: that will be hard to do without a look at the source.

Comment: Yep, it's being called from Javascript in the WebView, which I imagine runs in a different thread. How do I run setVisibility in the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
YourActivity.runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
});
```